# Installing linux on OCZ RevoDrive3 x2

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, ssd

First of all, here is the configuration of my computer:

- Motherboard: Asus H87Plus
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance 32GB
- Processor: Intel i7 4770
- Drive: OCZ RevoDrive 3 x2 (240 GB) (OCZ Revodrive3 is a
  PCIe module)

I am trying to install the latest version of Ubuntu Desktop (13.10). The problem is that in the UEFI (bios) the drive shows up as a 240 GB drive, but in the Ubuntu installer it shows up as two 120 GB drives. If I install Ubuntu in any of these two drives, it never boots. The screen flickers a few times and comes back to the UEFI menu. I have tried reading up and have come across information that the drive has a "fakeraid", and the solution is to use dmraid. However, when I give the following commands in the terminal (from live CD):

```
# modprobe dm_mod
# dmraid -ay
```

it says: `no raid disks`. And the following command:

```
# ls -la /dev/mapper/
```

just shows `/dev/mapper/control`

How can I install Ubuntu on my computer? what is the correct method?

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu on a standard SSD or HDD, OCZ has drivers but they don't support booting under Ubuntu.

Source: http://ocz.com/consumer/download/drivers

It seems the OCZ 350 drivers will work. You may find this interesting.

Source: http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?98087-OCZ-RevoDrive-3-X2-Linux-driver-AVAILABLE&p=782050&viewfull=1#post782050

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, the thing was that the motherboard was not smart enough to know how to boot from a device attached via a PCI.

To solve it, either you install your boot loader on a separate ATA drive or on a usb stick (as I did).